# Count words in menu titles, slice depending on length, then add line break

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery script and I am needing to modify it to allow me to filter the text in the menu item titles and insert a `<br>` after the first word if there are only two words in the title or after the second word if there are three or more words in the title. I have attached a screenshot of the design prototype showing how the menu items should display.

[image: Menu item titles example]

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){    
        var node = $("#navigation li a").contents().filter(function () { return this.nodeType == 3 }).first(),
        text = node.text(),
        first = text.slice(0, text.indexOf(" "));

        if (!node.length)
            return;

        node[0].nodeValue = text.slice(first.length);
        node.before(first + '<br/>');

    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at below approach:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navigation li a").each(function() {

      var text = $(this).text();
      var wordArray = text.split(" ");
      if (wordArray.length == 2) {
        $(this).html(wordArray.join('</br>'));
      } else if (wordArray.length > 2) {
        $(this).html(wordArray.slice(0, 2).join(' ') + '</br>' + wordArray.slice(2).join(' '));
      }

    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a>First Menu</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>Two Words</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>More Than Two</a>
  </li>
  <li><a>More Than Four Words In Menu</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here we are iterating over all the `<a>` tags which are part of our navigation menu and simply we are fetching their text to check length of it.